# Defining a function that that evaluates a function to obtain a value not supplied as an optional argument

Tags: function-construction

I have a function like this

```
CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, v0_, dt_, t_]
```

Now, I want to add a new parameter

```
u0 = u[α_, β_, λ_]
```

as an optional without rewriting the function.  Even I have tried

```
CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, u0:_u[α_, β_, λ_], v0_, dt_, t_]
```

but it does not work.  Any suggestions ?

#### Edit

To clarify my question, I post a part of my code:

```
CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, v0_, dt_, t_]:= 
  Module[{sMatrix, mMatrix, dMatrix, disp, velo, accel, result, index, reff, 
          effStiffnessMatrix},
    sMatrix = lumpingMatrix[stiffnessMatrix[α]];
    mMatrix = lumpingMatrix[massMatrix[β]];
    dMatrix = lumpingMatrix[dampMatrix[α1, α2]];
    disp[0] = u[α, β, λ]; (*initial displacement*)
    velo[0] = v0;
    accel[0] = -Inverse[mMatrix].(dMatrix.velo[0] + sMatrix.disp[0]);
    effStiffnessMatrix = 1/dt^2 mMatrix + 1/(2 dt) dMatrix;
    For[index = 0, index < Floor[t/dt], index++,
      reff = 
        sMatrix.disp[index] + 1/(2 dt) dMatrix.disp[index - 1] +
          mMatrix.(2 disp[index] - disp[index - 1])*1/dt^2;
      disp[index + 1] = reff/Diagonal[effStiffnessMatrix];
      result = Insert[result, disp[index + 1]];
      result]
```

In most cases, the default initial displacement, `disp[0]`, is known to be `u[α, β, λ]`. However, I sometimes want to use another initial condition, `disp[0] = u0`, where `U0` is an arbitrary vector given to `CentralDifferentMethod` as an argument.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "without rewriting the function"? What is going to happen with this $u0?$

Comment: @IgorRivin Because I use the default value for u() and now I want it can be changed.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here.  I am going to close this question until it is clarified, which I surely hope it will be as it will probably interest me.  The expression `u[α_, β_, λ_]` is not a function.  You need to include examples of the input and output of this function.  As it stands you only have pseudo-code for the left-hand-side.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have posted the code, I hope you have a look.

Comment: Since your question is closed, I will have to write my answer as comment, which will make it hard to read. Sorry about that. The easiest way to accomplish what you ask for requires a some rewriting, but not much. First change your current definition to `CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, v0_, dt_, t_, uo_] := Module{...}, ... disp[0] = u0; ...]` and then add a 2nd definition `CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, v0_, dt_, t_] := CentralDifferentMethod[α, β, α1, α2, λ, v0, dt, t, u[α, β, λ]]`.

Comment: @m_goldberg Question reopened.

Comment: I would like to thank for all your help. The code works well and more elegant now.

Comment: @m_goldberg Don't forget to post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question, so will try this to see if it's in the right direction. Consider the following collection of definitions for a function f[ ]

```
f[x_] := x^2;
f[x_, y_] := f[x] + y^3;
f[x_, y_, z_] := f[x, y] + f[x, z] + Sqrt[z];
f[x_, y_, z_, s_] := x y z s;
```

Every time you add a new parameter, you need only define how you want it to act with that new parameter. As you can see from the above, the functions can (though need not) have any relationship with each other.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish what you ask for requires a some rewriting, but not much. First change your current definition to

```
CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, v0_, dt_, t_, u0_] := 
  Module[{sMatrix, mMatrix, dMatrix, disp, velo, accel, index, reff, effStiffnessMatrix},
    sMatrix = lumpingMatrix[stiffnessMatrix[α]];
    mMatrix = lumpingMatrix[massMatrix[β]];
    dMatrix = lumpingMatrix[dampMatrix[α1, α2]];
    disp[0] = u0;
    velo[0] = v0;
    accel[0] = -Inverse[mMatrix].(dMatrix.velo[0] + sMatrix.disp[0]);
    effStiffnessMatrix = 1/dt^2 mMatrix + 1/(2 dt) dMatrix;
    For[index = 0, index < Floor[t/dt], index++, 
      reff = sMatrix.disp[index] + 1/(2 dt) dMatrix.disp[index - 1] + 
        mMatrix.(2 disp[index] - disp[index - 1])*1/dt^2;
    disp[index + 1] = reff/Diagonal[effStiffnessMatrix];
    Insert[result, disp[index + 1]]]
```

and then add a second definition

```
CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, v0_, dt_, t_] := 
  CentralDifferentMethod[α, β, α1, α2, λ, v0, dt, t, u[α, β, λ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be difficult to avoid some change to the function.

```
CentralDifferentMethod[α_, β_, α1_, α2_, λ_, v0_, dt_, t_, u0_: False] := Module[{ ...},
  If[SameQ[u0, False],
     disp[0] = u[α, β, λ];(*initial displacement*)
     disp[0] = u0];
  ...
```

Note it is usual to place default values at the end of the input parameters, otherwise it can be confusing to tell which values are which when they are omitted, e.g.

```
j[v_: 0, w_, x_: 1, y_, z_: 2] := jp[v, w, x, y, z]
j[a, b]
```

> jp[0, a, 1, b, 2]

```
j[a, b, c]
```

> jp[a, b, 1, c, 2]

Comment: You might use `u0_: True` and them `If[TrueQ[u0], . . .]`.